# Error Converting byte code to dex in android

Tags: android, android-studio, runtimeexception, dex

When I run app below error occurs:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

then I enabled multidex :
multiDexEnabled true
Then I do **Clean Project** and **Make Project**  and then below errors occur:

```
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
 Information:BUILD FAILED in 38s
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;
Information:See complete output in console
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Information:15 errors
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Information:0 warnings
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
```

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: `Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;` -- you have two different copies of Volley in your dependencies. You need to remove one.

Comment: okay.. Thank you .. i remove one copy of volley ..now i am trying to run app but delete fail internal error occur..  `$ adb push G:\Android\Fundraiser\BuyForFund\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.android.buyforfund
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.android.buyforfund"
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Invalid apk]


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.android.buyforfund
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK`   @CommonsWare